# NumPy Instead of for-loop for function with multiplication and addition

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

(python 2)

My for-loop is this

```
vx2=[]
vy2=[]
vz2=[]

for xn in range(0,npoints-2):
     vx11=vx1[xn]+.5*(fxxx_list[xn]+fxxx_list[xn+1])*dt
     vy11=vy1[xn]+.5*(fxxx_list[xn]+fxxx_list[xn+1])*dt
     vz11=vz1[xn]+.5*(fxxx_list[xn]+fxxx_list[xn+1])*dt 

     vx2.append(vx11)
     vy2.append(vy11)
     vz2.append(vz11) 
     print vx2, vy2, vz2
```

My prof. told me I could speed this up by replacing my for-loops by just operating on Numpy arrays, but I found that multiplying non-integers and adding/multiplying in the same Numpy function was inefficient. Is there an elegant way to write this using Numpy instead of a for-loop?

I've already tried this:

```
#number of iterations
xn=n1[0:998]
array=np.array(xn)


vxn=vx1[0:998]
vyn=vy1[0:998]
vzn=vz1[0:998]


vvv=np.multiply((dt),(fxxx_list))
vx2=vxn+vvv
vy2=vyn+vvv
vz2=vzn+vvv
```

But I couldn't get my algorithm enitrely correct and as you can see it's kind of a mess and takes just as long as the for-loop.

Comment: What is `fxxx_list? `vx1`?

Comment: fxxx_list is 999 lists with 999 elements each. I get it by manipulating a textfile I read in. I explain my code a little bit more in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563163/how-to-speed-up-a-python-2-program-with-multiple-nested-for-loops

Comment: To get numpy speed this list of lists has to be turned into array. That is a nontrivial time consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fxxx_list = np.array(fxxx_list)
vx = np.array([vx1,vy1,vy2])

vx11, vy11, vz11 = vx + (fxxx_list[:-2] + fxxx_list[1:-1])/2  * dt
```

If the arrays vx1,... are also of lenght n_points, than you should use

```
vx = np.array([vx1,vy1,vy2])[:,:-2]
```

NOTE: I'am assuming that vx1,... are all of the same length

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. However, I'm getting the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'. I'm working on it, but so far it still hasn't worked.

Comment: Also, I think it should be vx = np.array([vx1,vy1,vz2])[:,:-2]

Comment: I got this to work actually, but for some reason I had to write vx , vy, and vz all in seperate lines.

Comment: It's weird, this did not give me any error on any version of python, and you should be able to write al the v*1 in 1 array and make use of numpy broadcasting.   By the error you write it seems that you didn't actually turn the list into an array. I did write   'fxxx_list = np.array(fxxx_list)' for a reason